# Flutter plugin link to native shared lib fails (RPATH not working)

Tags: android, cmake, java-native-interface, flutter, native

I'm building a Flutter plugin for a native libopenocf.so (in C). I wrote a JNI wrapper libopenocflutter.so that links to libopenocf.so. The build works and puts all the shared libs in the correct place in the apk. However the link from libopenocflutter.so to libopenocf.so is the absolute path from the development environment, so when I load libopenocflutter.so from java I get a dlopen error lib not found.

I tried using various RPATH directives in my CMakeLists.txt based what I found from googling, e.g.

add_library(openocflib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(openocflib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
      "${distribution_DIR}/openocf/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopenocf.so")
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH    TRUE )
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH               "$ORIGIN::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::" ) SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH FALSE)
add_library(openocflutter SHARED ... c files ...)
target_link_libraries(openocflutter openocflib android log)

I've tried many variations but nothing works. The link always ends up like so (from readelf -d):

0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [/Users/gar/openocflutter/android/src/main/cpp/../../../libs/openocf/lib/arm64-v8a/libopenocf.so]

...

0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libopenocflutter.so]

Anybody know the secret sauce for this?

Thanks,

Gregg

Comment: PS. The CMakeLists.txt code from the sample app from Android NDK does not work: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/hello-libs/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/dropbox/djinni (for integration on both android and ios)? Also, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7053 for discussion of this topic.

Comment: I have the same issue, have you figured it out?